# will converting my foreign keys to strings solve my circular reference issue in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, circular-dependency

My django project has a circular reference issue.

My models are too many to post here.  Will converting all my models foreign keys to strings solve my problem?

Like this:

```
group = models.ForeignKey('groups.Group')
```

Also, I am using django 1.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a string in the foreign key will solve some circular import issues, but it's still possible to have other circular import issues.

Since you haven't posted your code, all I can suggest is trying it to see whether it fixes your problem.